# Why is it easier to measure the specific charge of an electron over the charge?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, history, charge

The electron was discovered in 1897 and the $e/m$ ratio was measured at that time ,but the charge $e$ itself was measured in 1911. Why  was it not possible to measure it earlier?

Comment: Bcoz no one could think of an experiment to measure it before 1911.

Comment: It is--from a practical point of view--a surprisingly difficult measurement to make when you don't know the mass of the electron either. People routinely fail to get it right using modern kit.

Answer (score 4):

Because $e/m_e$ appears in macroscopic equations, but $e,m_e$ individually do not.

The force equation for a general electron in an electromagnetic field is $F=e(...)$. This makes acceleration proportional to $\frac{e}{m_e}$.

Acceleration is not that hard to measure, especially if you measure it in the form of deflection. Piping electrons from a beta emitter into a calibrated magnetic field will give you a deflection in their path, and this can be measured by having them strike a phosphor screen.

So, $\frac{e}{m_e}$ is easy to measure.

On the other hand, it is hard to measure $e$ and $m_e$. To do so we would need to create a system where the force is acting only on the electron, but it is attached to a larger, measurable mass. This replaces the $m_e$ in $F=m_ea=e(...)$ with a larger $m$, and now from experiment we can measure $e$.

That's exactly what Millikan did when he measured $e$. He took oil drops with charges that were small multiples of $e$. The mass of the drops could be calculated from their behavior in freefall<sup>1</sup>, and the electrostatic force required to balance them is measured.

<sup>1. While Galileo's ball drop experiment tells us that the behavior of a falling body doesn't depend on mass; this is no longer applicable when we consider viscosity, and thus by carefully monitoring the behavior we can determine the mass of a falling drop.</sup>

Comment: I couldn't quite catch the title!